# Print arraylist elements issues

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having problem with using `ArrayList`. First I'm new to Java, I'm trying to use `ArrayList` to store objects and now I want to print out all objects thats are items of the `ArrayList`. But somehow, the `List` printed out improperly, there are duplicated items (i'm sure there is only one item of them). Here are my code:

```
StringBuilder description = new StringBuilder();
    for (Unit u: diary.getUnitCollection()){
        for (AssessmentItem a: u.getAssessmentCollection()){
            for (Task t: a.getTaskCollection()){
                description.append(t.toString());
            }
            description.append(a.toString());
        }
        description.append(u.toString());
    }
```

and this is the result, as you can see, they are duplicated:

```
Java-Ass1
Java-Ass2
Java-Ass1
Java-Ass2
```

If I print the UnitCollection only, its display correctly but the format like this [item,..], I want to know what's wrong in the for loop.

Comment: I suggest you print a log to find out whats wrong. From the code you posted, nobody can tell where the result string is coming from (i'm assuming one of the `toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can exist only two possibilities:

1) Your list contains same element - it is not set and it is possible
2) Some of your toString methods call another. For example u.toString() call  a.toString() inside it or a.toString() call t.toString()

Comment: You're rite on the money mate. I was ways over my head abt the for loop, but as your 2nd option reference, I went back to the class and see I did list its items in toString() using iterator. and now all works. Tks mate